# Spell checking for ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, spell-checking

I am jooking for a free spell check for ArcMap 10.1.
Someone wrote a VBA for pre-10 [here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/ArcMap/SpellcheckTextElementsinArcMap.htm).

Is there a way to implement it in 10.1, perhaps writing it in python instead of VBA?

Answer (score 2):

The [Spell Check Text Elements in ArcMap](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/ArcMap/SpellcheckTextElementsinArcMap.htm) uses "Microsoft Word to do spell checking for ArcMap".

To investigate spell checking text elements using ArcPy and Python, I [searched](http://www.google.com/search?q=python%20spell%20check) and found [pyenchant](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant/) which has some code samples in a [Spell Checker for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928155/spell-checker-for-python) Q&A at Stack Overflow.

There are many Q&As here at GIS SE that will help with the ArcPy side of reading strings from text elements and replacing them with spell-checked strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python based spell checker for ArcGIS that currently works with English, French and German.  There are four toolbox tools that will check the spelling of the layout items (title, legend, text), an attribute column, some annotation texts, or the table of contents.  The tools provide word suggestions and the text items are updated during spell-checking.  The installation files include instructions on how to add other language dictionaries (there are over 100 available) but the tool interfaces are in English.  I have included  Russian, Arabic, Italian, and Spanish dictionary files and those can be added after installation.  There is an extensive read me file along with the project files here:
https://github.com/gerry1138/ArcGIS-Spell-Checker